# weird issue with html: markup is correct but dev tools show <title> moving to <body>

Tags: html, html-parsing

I've got this weird issue going on. I'm using Codeigniter 3.0-dev and Smarty 3.1.4 in the backend, but I don't think it's relevant.

I have this really simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>some page</title>
</head>
<body>
asd
</body>
</html>
```

now. when I view the source of this page, on any browser (tried Opera 10.52, Firefox 7.0.1, Chrome 14 and 15, IE9) the markup is exactly like above. now, when I use firebug or chrome's dev tools it moves the title tag in the `<body>`, and if I have meta or anything else in the `<head>`, it moves those items in the `<body>` aswell. firefox's firebug shows me this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<title>test</title>
asd
</body>
</html>
```

why does this happen? any ideas, at all?

Comment: I'll get on it, but it will take some time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elements that appear to be in `head` in the mark-up, can end up inside `body` in the DOM, if the parser sees something before the moved elements that is only permissible in the body of HTML. For example, a **double** BOM (byte-order-mark) at the start of the file may not show up in `View Source`, but will cause the parser to think that it has entered the html body section, and all the `head` elements in the mark-up will end up in the `body` in the DOM.

Comment: where should I start looking for BOM? Smarty backend? codeigniter backend? my template files? (I also added a comment above which should've bee under this post)

Comment: @Valhallen - Sorry, I don't know anything about Smarty or CodeIgniter, so I can't help you there. For looking for a BOM, I recommend using a Hex Editor, so you can inspect the individual bytes. The BOM should show up in the first few bytes of the file.

Comment: I found out that it is indeed an issue with BOM. it seems my editor adds something that screwes up the parsing

Answer (score 0):

What Alohci said, plus both Firebug and the Chrome debugger often move things around to suit themselves. The source then looks wrong when viewed in those debuggers.

Comment: while browsing the file, I tried saving it from firefox. the result file had the wrong HTML code. so BOM seems plausible indeed. there is some sort of whitespace displayed by the dev tools too.
what's the best way to find byte order marks in a file? I know UltraEdit has some issues with it.